# How to Track Click Event on Google One Tap Sign In

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

I implemented Google One Tap sign in on my website. The issue I am trying to tackle is how can I track whenever a user clicks the "Continue as X" button. Google one tap is an iframe and doesn't bubble its event listeners to the parent window object, and google doesn't send postMessages indicating such events. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to listen to the click the same way the Sign in With Google button flow [can](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#click_listener). However, you can [PromptMomentNotification](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#PromptMomentNotification) to gain some insights on the users' clicks on One Tap. Be mindful that, some of the methods/fields would change or go way when One Tap with FedCM. See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/fedcm-migration#migrate_your_web_app) for more information.